Convolution of Continuous Signal and Rectangular Function
I have some math problems that require me to convolve a continuous sine function with a rectangular function, which involves Heaviside functions. Here is the math that I've done to solve the problem.
$x(t) = \sin(2\pi t)$
$h(t) = u(t)-u(t-1)$
$y(t) = x(t) * h(t)$
First, I observed the non-overlapping region ($t < 0$ and $t > 1$)
$\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi t-2\pi\tau)d\tau$
$\int_0^1[\sin(2\pi t)\cos(2\pi\tau)-\cos(2\pi t)\sin(2\pi\tau)]d\tau$
$\sin(2\pi t)\int_0^1\cos(2\pi\tau)d\tau-\cos(2\pi t)\int_0^1\sin(2\pi\tau)d\tau$
$\sin(2\pi t)[\sin2\pi-\sin 0 ]+ \cos(2\pi t)[\cos2\pi-\cos 0 ]$
$\sin(2\pi t) \times 0+ \cos(2\pi t) \times 0 = 0$
The result makes sense to me because the integral of the sine signal within a window whose length is its own fundamental period leads to two values of areas that cancel each other out when they are summed.
Then, I observed the overlapping region. Integral limit changed to $0$ to $t$
$\sin(2\pi t)\int_0^t\cos(2\pi\tau)d\tau-\cos(2\pi t)\int_0^t\sin(2\pi\tau)d\tau$
$\sin(2\pi t)[\sin(2\pi t)-\sin 0 ]+ \cos(2\pi t)[\cos(2\pi t)-\cos 0 ]$
$\sin^2 (2\pi t)+ \cos^2(2\pi t)- \cos(2\pi t)] = 1-\cos(2\pi t)$
It concludes that,
$y(t) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t < 0$ and $t>1$} \\[2ex]
1-\cos(2\pi t), & \text{if $0\le t \le 1$}
\end{cases}$
I'm not very confident about the results. I believe I may have missed some concepts about convolution or any math that I used. My primary reference for doing convolution is M. J. Roberts' book titled 'Signal and System.' The graphical representation of convolution has helped me a lot in understanding and operating convolution.
I really appreciate all your assistance in helping me justify the above results and find the correct answers for the mentioned problem. Many thanks!

$$y(t) = \begin{cases} 0,  & \text{if $t < 0$ and $t>1$} \ \frac{1-\cos(2\pi t)}{\color{red}{2\pi}}, & \text{if $0\le t \le 1$} \end{cases}$$
